# Disqus comments are overlapping my footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, disqus

I have spent 10 hours on this issue but I am still unable to solve it. I am using bootstrap 3 with disqus comments. Somehow disqus comments are overlapping my footer. See following picture.

[image]

I have tried many tricks but none of them worked.

Following is my HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sections">
        <div class="row">
            .... truncated unnecessary code
            <div id="comments">
                <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    .....
</footer>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
}
.sections {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-bottom: #d8d8d8 solid 1px;
    height: auto !important;
}
#comments {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 350px;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Changed iframe size using js but it does not work

   setInterval(function() {

   ```
   $('#comments').css({
       'height': $('#disqus_thread').height() + 'px'
       });
   }, 1000);
   ```
2. Changed disqus_thread height to 400px but it does not change the height when new comments are posted
3. Used disqus onReady event to change the height of iframe but this one is also not working. Perhaps, disqus comments are loading after calling onReady event?

JS Code

```
this.callbacks.onReady = [function() {
    resizeIframeWidth($('#disqus_thread iframe'));
}];

function resizeIframeWidth(e){
    // Set width of iframe according to its content
    if (e.Document && e.Document.body.scrollWidth) //ie5+ syntax
        e.width = e.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    else if (e.contentDocument && e.contentDocument.body.scrollWidth) //ns6+ & opera syntax
        e.width = e.contentDocument.body.scrollWidth + 35;
    else (e.contentDocument && e.contentDocument.body.offsetWidth) //standards compliant syntax – ie8
    e.width = e.contentDocument.body.offsetWidth + 35;
}
```

Comment: I would assume a simple `overflow: auto;` rule for `#comments` would fix that.

Comment: @TiesonT. It didn't work. It created a lot of empty whitespace and also disqus comments were disappeared. I just solved this problem. See my answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by removing `position:relative` from `.sections` css rule.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the loaded events like this

```
     // called by disqus 
     function disqus_config() {
        this.callbacks.onReady = [function() {  
           // if your code respond to this event to resize the sidebar
           $(window).trigger('resize'); 
     }]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a heap of things it could be and you'd need to provide a link to your site where this occurs to diagnose properly.  A code sample just isn't enough as the problem will becoming from your site's CSS (most likely).

Probably culprits:

1. no "clear:both" property on or between the comments and your footer.
2. alternatively, try `clear:both;` to #comments
3. the footer element has some crazy negative top margin, or has position: absolute.

I understand that it's jQuery that is causing a dynamically loaded object to break things.  But the solution will actually be bullet proof CSS in my opinion.

Ensure that the following CSS properties:

```
clear:both;
width: 100%;
display:block;
float: none;
```

Are applied to the footer & comments ID's/elements or alternatively, that you have a full width block clearing element between the main area and the comments AND the comments and the footer.  Alternatively, you might just get away with applying these to the #comments div (ie: just making it self clear, regardless of how high it goes).

If this STILL isn't working, put overflow:hidden on your #comments.  It won't be wonderful, but at least it will stop the behaviour you describe :)

Comment: Thanks Spanka for your answer. I just solved this problem. There was another css rule set for `.sections` I simply removed position:relative and it worked fine.

Comment: Glad you got a win!  You should inspect .sections in firebug though - just make sure that the footer/disqus elements are in fact cleared properly, otherwise you might run into issues later that are like this: not immediately apparent as to the source of the issue.